# How do the shaders work in Android OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

When developing Andoird OpenGL, how do the created vertex and fragment shaders work?

I am basically following the Android developer guide example on OpenGL ES. However, when creating the shaders, first it creates a String including a code segment. I tried to understand how does this string segment connect with the remaining process, but I couldn't.

```
 private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;"+
            "void main(){"+
            "   gl_position = vPosition;"+
            "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the Graphics Pipeline:

[image]

The main job of a vertex shader is converting/transforming the position of each vertex, from **Camera (Real-world) Space** to a special space called **Normalized Device Space**. The output position is stored in the built-int variable `gl_Position`. Each vertex is executed by an instance of the vertex shader. So if you have 100 vertices, you will have 100 instances of the vertex shader executed.

Your posted vertex shader code actually does not do any significant convert: `gl_position = vPosition` but this is fine as the author intended that the input positions are already in the **Normalized Device Space**.

Then in the **Normalized Device Space**, these positions are assembled into primitives (e.g., triangles). Next, in the **Rasterization** stage, these primitives are broken into fragments (can be considered pixels for the sake of simplicity). Then each fragment goes into the fragment shader to calculate the color of that fragment. Each fragment is executed by an instance of the fragment shader.

At one time, one and only one couple of vertex shader & fragment shader is used in the pipeline. This is specified by the OpenGL ES command `glUseProgram(program)` in which a program is just a couple of vertex & fragment shaders.

The string you posted is the source code of a vertex shader, you will see there is also the source code of a corresponding fragment shader. We use OpenGL ES commands to create shaders, set their source code (the string segment you saw), compile them, attach them to a program, link the program, and use the program.

In order to really understand all of these stuff, I suggest you to read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321502795). The picture above is taken from that book.